# Script for Auto saving every page I visit to Wayback Machine

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to create a script for Tampermonkey. 
The purpose of the script will be to add every website I visited on Internet Archive/Wayback Machine without using any Addon/Bookmarklet. 
like [this](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/368062-autosave-to-internet-archive-wayback-machine). This script is not working anymore.

Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks

Comment: [Flagging as "Needs more focus"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277139/question-asking-for-you-to-write-code).

Comment: @Danial H. what do you mean by "save"?? Like, saving to computer??

Comment: still unclear.. Please add more details

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd I want to save it automatically on Wayback Machine i.e. when i open a new tab or visit a website, It will auto add respective site to wayback

Comment: pretty hard to figure out... do they expose any API which can help PUT pages??

Comment: you can setup an extension which will load the website in a separate tag, then take the URL of the current tab and paste it in the "Save Page Now" section

Comment: There is only one snippet available which I'm unable to figure out how to use:
window.open("http://web.archive.org/save/" + document.location.href);

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd is there any helpful link for that?

Comment: @DanialH. See https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php